# Android retrofit 2 multi part response parsing

Tags: android, retrofit2

I am using Retrofit 2 for my restful call. But one of the response body is multi part(ie; it contains 2 content types. One is application/json and the other is application/octet-stream) and I cannot parse it. I have found an issue reported on it. So if someone have faced the same issue and have solved it then please let me know the alternative method you have chosen.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you provide details about issue which you are facing?

Comment: The response that I am getting from the server contains 2 portions.. first one with a json response type and the other is an image which is in octet-stream. I am able to collect the data to ResponseBody attribute. But there is no idea about how to parse it